# Copying files between folders of Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to copy files from one folder inside jupyter notebook to another folder.

For example :

There are some .ipynb files, text files, excel sheets,  folders(Hi)

Now I have created another folder named "Hello" and want to copy all the contents of folder "Hi" inside jupyter itself so what will be the desired path to copy ?

Answer (score 1):

This would be snippet for one file and then you can put it in a loop in combination with os library methods

`import shutil

source_path = "path of the file you want to move"

destination_path = "path of the destination folder"

shutil.move(source_path, destination_path)`

Comment: This code will work if we want to move file from one location to another apart from Jupyter notebook folders.

Comment: I want to know how can we actually copy one folder containing many files within jupyter files tab to another folder in jupyter file tab.